# Serializing a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, c++, serialization, data-structures, binary-search-tree

How exactly does one go about serializing a BST? What is the correct way to do it in the most efficient way? Now, this is way too general, so let me explain what I mean.

Here is some pseudo-pseudocode :

```
public int[] serialize(root){
    preorder traversal 
    convert node to binary representation
    add the binary representation to an array
    send array via stream
}
```

Or

```
public int serialize(root){
    preorder traversal 
    convert node to binary representation
    send the binary representation via stream
}
```

My question is -- creating an array and sending it full of bits, is this efficient? Or should I skip the whole array idea and every time a node is converted, send it out to deserialize it? Perhaps both of these implementations are stupid. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "best" solution may depend on how the tree is represented, so it's hard to say without knowing more about this tree. But I'd skip the array step if it's unnecessary (which it sounds like it is) and just serialize the bits out.

Comment: what do you mean how the tree is represented? it's a BST. smaller on left, larger on right

Comment: I mean how it's internally represented. You can represent BSTs as nodes and references (a la linked lists) or as arrays, for example (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees)).

Comment: oh, sorry. this was more for linked list versions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you also take a look at google protocol buffers
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tree and the type of data. If the order of nodes in the tree matter, you need to store enough information to recreate it. If it's in an array, you can use the position in the array to recreate the structure

Comment: isn't it obvious that the order of nodes matter? It's a BST..  (since traversing it in preorder outputs an exact copy when inserting into a new one) . but what i was really asking..was more about serialization i suppose..whether it matters if i send an array full of bits, or bits one at a time

Comment: there can be elements that are "equal" by the compareTo function and when recreating it, the order can be different. But you are right, the functionality will be the same

Answer (score 0):

BST can be only serialized in post-order, as pre-order and in-order are not unique.

1) non-unique in pre-order

```
      root                     root
    /     \                   / 
  left    right             left
                               \
                               right
```

2) non-unique in in-order

```
     1                 1
    /                   \    
   2                     2
```

Comment: Both examples are incorrect because they violate the BST definition. In the first example, we assume "right" is bigger than "root", so it is impossible to have a BST with "right" in the left subtree. In the second example, the first tree is not a valid BST because 2 cannot be a left child of 1.

Answer (score 0):

If by "streams" you're talking about C++ iostreams, they're already buffered at a reasonable size and the cost of inserting into that buffer is very low.  The standard library is mature; beating it at its own game is very hard. and you'll need exploitable specifics you can take advantage of to get anything worthwhile.  That said:

How big your output buffer should be (with the degenerate case being a single-element buffer, i.e. no buffering) depends on the overhead of a buffer flush. That overhead will have a fixed cost and a size-related cost -- not a simple linear one given cache effects.  With more expensive fixed overhead bigger buffers help amortize the fixed expense.  For instance, if a buffer flush can trigger zero-copy I/O it can be dramatically cheaper to buffer all of a largish serialization, but if the output operation is going to be copying your source buffer, buffer sizes down around a quarter of your L1 cache size are a decent choice when the fixed cost of a flush is low.

None of this matters at all unless the time serialization takes puts it on a critical path, i.e. makes it what a user's waiting on -- for something like this, that's getting hard to produce unless you're talking about millions of items and up. Even then, if you haven't already worked on it it's almost certain there's more waste in how you produce an individual serialization than in the buffering scheme you choose -- and even *then* never forget what you're racing.  Is it I/O bandwidth?  Sending your serialized stream through a low-grade compressor could easily save more time than anything you could do up front.